# Using preprocessor macros to define primitive values as function arguments using SWIG

Tags: c, swig

Let's say I have the following macro in my C code:

```
#if __SOME_CONDITION__
#define SAMPLE_TYPE double
#elif
#define SAMPLE_TYPE float
#endif
```

which basically defines `SAMPLE_TYPE` to be one of two possible primitive types depending on another compiler directive/other preprocessor definition.

I have the following header for a class that I wrap using SWIG:

```
class SomethingStatic {
    public:
        static SAMPLE_TYPE someFunction();
}
```

when I build and wrap the code and reference `SomethingStatic.someFunction` from my Java code, the return type is given as `SWIGTYPE_p_SAMPLE_TYPE`, which has also been generated by SWIG.

How can I configure SWIG to return the primitive `float` or `double` value the macro evaluates to?

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but SWIG might understand what you're doing better if you used typedefs instead of #defines.

Comment: @zwol sadly it provides the same behaviour as a typedef.

Comment: Preprocess the code before letting SWIG see it?  Probably not the best way, but it is what immediately springs to mind.

Comment: It has been quite a while since I used `#define` or `typedef` for handling primitive types. Today, I use templates and here SWIG always handles it correctly. The downside is that you need explicitly instantiate your templates using the `%template` syntax

Comment: That should work fine.  Make sure the header for the SAMPLE_TYPE definition is directly `%include`ed in the `.i` file.  SWIG doesn't recurse into header files by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWIG understands the preprocessor, but you must `%include` the header with the direct definition.  SWIG doesn't recurse into other headers included by a header.  Also make sure to declare the preprocessor values when calling `swig` as well as the compiler.

##### Example:

condition.h

```cpp
#ifdef CONDITION
#define SAMPLE_TYPE double
#else
#define SAMPLE_TYPE int
#endif
```

class.h

```py
#include "condition.h"

class SomethingStatic {
public:
    static SAMPLE_TYPE someFunction() {
    #ifdef CONDITION
        return 1.5;
    #else
        return 2;
    #endif
    }
};
```

test.i

```cpp
%module test

// This code is directly included in the wrapper.
// C++ will process condition.h implicitly
%{
#include "class.h"
%}

// Headers that SWIG will create wrappers for.
// SWIG *does not* recurse into subheaders by default.

%include "condition.h" // must be explicit with SWIG
%include "class.h"
%}
```

Using "swig -python -c++ test.i" and compiling without /DCONDITION:

```py
>>> import test
>>> x=test.SomethingStatic()
>>> x.someFunction()
2
```

Using "swig -DCONDITION -python -c++ test.i" and compiling with /DCONDITION:

```py
>>> import test
>>> x=test.SomethingStatic()
>>> x.someFunction()
1.5
```

Demo if you comment out the `%include "condition.h"` line, which seems to be the OP's original issue:

```py
>>> import test
>>> x=test.SomethingStatic()
>>> x.someFunction()
<Swig Object of type 'SAMPLE_TYPE *' at 0x000001D369F9B4E0>
```

Comment: That did it! By specifying the header in the _%include_ section of the interface file I got it to work as expected. In retrospect it makes sense *cough* but I completely overlooked that the defines were inside a file that was referenced only inside the C code, instead of exposed through SWIG. Thanks!